# How to split long strings in IntelliJ IDEA automatically?

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea

I am writing a test with very long strings, and I need to split those strings:

```
private static final String TOO_LONG_JSON = "{field1:field1, field2:field2 ... fieldN:fieldN}";
```

so they would become:

```
private static final String TOO_LONG_JSON = "{field1:field1, field2:field2" + 
    "{field3:field3, field4:field4,field6:field6, field7:field7}" +
    "{field8:field8, field9:field9,field10:field10, field11:field11}" +
    " ... fieldN:fieldN}";
```

Is it possible to set up IntelliJ IDEA to automatically split those long strings?

Comment: Are you changing the content of the string?

Comment: No just split it with `+` sign. For example it possible to configure Intellin to wrap code line that more than 80 symbols, I need something similar with too long strings.

Comment: Look into code formatting shortcuts.

Comment: I am looking, but what exactly I have to see? :)

Comment: I agree with commenters below that the latest version of IntelliJ doesn't break the string with code formatting.  However, you can move your cursor inside the string and press Enter to split the string manually.

Answer (score 46):

You can use auto-formatting by running the `Reformat code` function
(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) after few changes in Code Style settings.

(alternatively `Reformat code`, <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on MacOS),

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open `Settings` window (or `Preferences`, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on MacOS)
- Go to `Code Style` menu, and choose `Java` submenu
- Go to `Wrapping and Braces` tab
- Make sure to **uncheck** `Line Breaks` option and **check** `Ensure right margin is not exceeded` option
- Press `OK` to accept changes you've made

Now when using auto-formatting (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> / MacOS <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) long strings exceeding line character limit will be automatically cut into multiple lines.

Comment: @GiliGaribi Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using? I've just tested it out on the newest one (currently 2017.3.5) and surely it works.
The "Line breaks" and "Ensure right margin is not exceeded" options are now under the "Wrapping and Braces" tab, but they still work as intended.

Comment: This made the problem worse for me. It still doesn't break long strings, but now it also messes up other code. Using 2017.3.5

Comment: Highlight the line with the string, if you don't wish to reformat the entire file

Comment: I cannot find this in version 2020.2.1

Comment: This is only present for Groovy.

Comment: 2022.2 Ultimate - this answer just plain doesn't work.

Comment: @cb4 Are you sure, you exactly followed the instructions? I've updated them to be a bit clearer about submenus, shortcuts and different systems, it works for me on both Window and macOS machines, [both Community and Ultimate versions](https://i.imgur.com/Jczyr0Q.png)

Comment: @mkierc Yes followed exactly. Your original answer was quite clear, but maybe add what your result looks like? I made sure that right margin setting was the same in `Code Style` and `Wrapping and Braces` (just in case). It is puzzling, but there must differences in other releated settings that are contributing to the differences in our results. I don't have time to figure this out right now (upcoming software deadline) but *definitely* would like to know the answer! I retracted my down vote.

Answer (score 3):

Same version - Community Edition. [image: Here's the relevant section]

Comment: By the way, it's working for long lines in general, but not to one line with a long string

Answer (score 1):

At least for me, code formatting options still don't do this in 2020.2.3 Ultimate version. It seems to only split the string on punctuation marks - `"fooofoooo.ffoooo"` is broken to `"fooofoooo" + "ffoooo"` but long string with letters in it is not split.

Only thing I've seen working consistently is to place your cursor within the string and press enter. That's hardly "automatically", but best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

**2022 UPDATE**
There is still *no answer* to what the OP asked - configure IntelliJ to "automatically split those long strings". The most upvoted answer does not work.

There is only one way (it's manual) to solve this problem short of someone writing a plugin. This method is guaranteed to work regardless of any other settings and provides 100% control of formatting of any code segment, not just those with long lines of strings.

Go to `Settings Editor | Code Style | Formatter` and enable the formatter on/off markers. Format the code fragment any way you want and surround it with the off/on phrases in code comments.

**My example code segment:**

```
System.out.println("This is a long line of text that includes " + variables() + " and " + some.otherStuff().toString() + ". But don't count on " + this.IDE().toName() + " to format it in " + anIntelligent() + " way. " + this.IDE().toName() + " should add a " + plusSign.Option() + " for long strings like this.");
```

**RESULT 1** With settings as described in @mkierc's answer with a hard wrap at 80 per OP:

```
    System.out.println(
        "This is a long line of text that includes " + variables() + " in " +
                "it and " + some.otherStuff()
                                                                                             .toString() + ". But don't count on " + this.IDE()
                                                                                                                                             .toName() + " to format it in " + anIntelligent() + " way. " + this.IDE()
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    .toName() + " should add a " + plusSign.Option() + " for long strings like this.");
```

I don't know how this could be worse. The hard wrap was not honored after the second line and the ending semi-colon is at column 300! Honestly, I can't imagine what algorithm led to this mess. My son at 10 years old could do better...

**RESULT 2** Formatted manually, margin at 80, and using formatter on/off markers:

```
//@formatter:off
System.out.println("This is a long line of text that includes " 
           + variables() + " in it and " + some.otherStuff().toString()
           + ". But don't count on " + this.IDE().toName() 
           + " to format it in " + anIntelligent() + " way. " 
           + this.IDE().toName() + " should add a " + plusSign.Option() 
           + " for long strings like this.");
//@formatter:on
```

It's possible that Result 1 can be improved with other settings. I tried a few seemingly relevant options and combinations thereof. None significantly changed the results.

Answer (score -1):

I had to paste a long SQL String for a native query in my application. 
I think the real solution is to put your cursor inside the "" marks of this line of code typed manually:
" " +

When you paste the LONG STRING of text inside the quotation marks, IntelliJ will format each line of code also with \t and \n inside, for you.

Comment: That didn't work