# Intellij toString multiline

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tostring

When auto-generating the toString method in `IntelliJ` it is putting all text onto a single line. Some of these lines are massive - how can I get Intellij to split the toString onto multi lines, after each new variable?

This is what I have:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" + " line1='" + line1 + '\'' + ", line2='" + line2 + '\'' + ", town='" + town + '\'' + ", county='" + county + '\'' + ", postcode='" + postcode + '\'' + ", country='" + country + '\'' + '}';
    }
```

And this is what I want:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" 
            + " line1='" + line1 + '\'' 
            + ", line2='" + line2 + '\'' 
            + ", town='" + town + '\'' 
            + ", county='" + county + '\'' 
            + ", postcode='" + postcode + '\'' 
            + ", country='" + country + '\'' + '}';
        }
```

I have tried creating a custom template but it just seems to ignore this.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376980/how-split-large-string-in-intellij-idea-automatically

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ's `String concat (+)` template produces output ~identical to the desired output shown in your question.

To engage this template ...

- `Code > Generate > toString`
- Choose Template: `String concat (+)`

If you need to tweak this template then click on `Settings` and choose the `Templates` tab and copy and create a copy of whichever existing template is closest to your needs, edit this copy and then it will appear in the `Template` dropdown for selection.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

If - after using this template - the output is in a single long line then it's possible that your chosen Java code formatter is reformatting the output produced by the `toString` template.

Comment: Something must be overriding the template then as I have not changed the default `String concat (+)` template.

Comment: Is it possible that your chosen Java code formatter is reformatting the output produced by the toString template?

Comment: Restoring the IntelliJ Code Style preferences to default resolved my issue. I think it was the `Line Breaks` option under `Preferences` > `Editor` > `Code style` > `Java` which needs to be ticked!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a template to generate toString() method's body with plus sign in the next line

1. Open templates setings  `toString() -> Settings -> Templates`
2. Clone `String concat(+)`
3. Use that content

```
public java.lang.String toString() {
#if ( $members.size() > 0 )
    #set ( $i = 0 )
return "$classname{"
    #foreach( $member in $members )
        #if ( $i == 0 )
            + "$member.name="##
        #else
            + ", $member.name="##
        #end
        #if ( $member.objectArray )
            + java.util.Arrays.toString($member.accessor)
        #elseif ( $member.primitiveArray && $java_version >= 5)
            + java.util.Arrays.toString($member.accessor)
        #elseif ( $member.string )
            + $member.accessor + '\''
        #else
            + $member.accessor
        #end
        #set ( $i = $i + 1 )
    #end
+ '}';
#else
return "$classname{}";
#end
}
```